# How to fix "Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException Image source not readable" error in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Thanks for checking out this post, I appreciate it!

Apologies I am aware of the clean ups that are being done on redundant posts from newbies so I hope I've provided information that is the most relevant!

I have been having issues with a "**Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
Image source not readable"** issue with Laravel for the past day with the code that's flagged, being -

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
Image source not readable

 if (request('image')) {
        $imagePath = request('image')->store('profile', 'public');
        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))- 
 >fit(1000, 1000);
        $image->save();
        $imageArray = ['image' => $imagePath];
    }
    auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge(
        $data,
        $imageArray ?? []
    ));
    return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");
    }
 }

Arguments
"make"
array:1 [▼
0 => "/home/forge/swiftagram.tk/public/storage/profile/x53rn0h8DGnxVAQdqtUjstQ0EBmL7ehOh1mjLDO2.jpeg"]
```

I have trawled through heaps of SO posts re the same issue yet to no avail, so I thought I would ask in hopes of some support, from great minds within the community! Things I have tried in terms of altering code, to name but a few:

"use path method of Storage facade."

changing the "Image::make" to "Image::file."

Try the "getRealPath()" in place of public_path.

Tried using absolute paths in full instead of the "storage/example"

I would post the full code here but fear it would turn into a phone book so if this does help - here is my public github repo link, as all the code I am currently using, is there:

https://github.com/TinkeringButReallyPlayingWithFire/Swiftagram/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProfilesController.php

https://github.com/TinkeringButReallyPlayingWithFire/Swiftagram/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php

The error occurs on both the "Profile" and "Post" controllers.

Again I apologise if this feels as if I'm dumping this for someone else to do, that is not my intention at all so I will happily take all advise given to sort this error out! :)

I am new to Laravel / PHP so please excuse any ghastly looking code!

Forgot to mention! - This worked fine on the local server, but I have recently deployed this to Laravel Forge and I am encountering this issue via the debugger!

*EDIT - Think it helps to know what I'm actually trying to achieve! - this site is an "instagram" clone in a sense and I should: fill in user details such as the profile bio's "title", "description" and "url" which works as intended. However the final step of the update form is to upload a profile image. The upload is via the file explorer window (the one to upload images etc from your local area to the browser), which then updates the user profile view.

Many thanks for reading!

***RESOLVED*** - Thanks for everything @afikri!!!!!!!

I managed to sort out the SSH as the keys were a pain to get right!

The command "php artisan storage:link" was linked on my local server but I had to link once again and it solved all the issues!

Appreciate you taking the time to help as I was changing the code and pretty much coming back to the same outcome but in different syntax! :D

Comment: perhaps storage permission need to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please run the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

on the forge side?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response!
I had to do some digging on how to run php artisan commands through forge and I came across using the scripts on the actual "deploy scripts" section of the site.
This is what my current script is:

cd /home/forge/swiftagram.tk,
git pull origin master,
php artisan key:generate,
composer install,
php artisan storage:link, 
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader,
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.3-fpm reload,

if [ -f artisan ],
then,
    php artisan migrate --force,
fi,

Comment: So far the issue is still present - unless the scripts didn't run "php artisan storage:link" as intended!

Comment: what about the path?are sure it is same on your forge side? $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))- 
 >fit(1000, 1000);

Comment: glad to help ;)